# Used to would do/except for/anything/everything

Tags: word-choice

Can I use either "except for" or "except" in my sentence and can't I use both "used to" and "would" "anything "and "everything"?

"The baby would/used to eat everything/anything except for meat, cheese, vegetables and cream cake.

Comment: It's certainly not "syntactically invalid" to include ***for*** in your cited context, but as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eat+anything+except+for+meat%2Ceat+anything+except+meat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceat%20anything%20except%20meat%3B%2Cc0) shows, native speakers / writers ***usually don't.***

Comment: It is also quite common to say "..would eat anything **but** meat, cheese ..."

Comment: @FumbleFingers, so a native speaker would say "The baby used to eat " as well as "would eat" but  do both "everything" and "anything" make sense?

Comment: _Used to_ implies that he/she is no longer willing to eat all those things.

Comment: @Kate Bunting,  doesn't *would* mean the same?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, and can't I use both "everything" and "anything"?

Comment: _Would_ doesn't necessarily mean 'no longer does' - it could be used in a story to refer to someone's habitual behaviour. Yes, you could use either _anything_ or _everything_.

Comment: @AntoniaA: I never mentioned anything about the ***would / used to*** choice here. But now I'm actually *thinking* about it, I'd say ***used to*** is more likely than ***would*** in this exact context. That's because the latter has stronger implications of ***was in the habit of...***, which tends to imply ***choice***, but I imagine the baby just ate whatever it was given (i.e. - the baby ***was fed on...***, rather than ***chose to eat...***). But as with many of your questions about such choices, in reality there's little if any difference between the different phrasings

Comment: @Kate Bunting, when you said "would doesn't necessarily mean no longer does" do you mean it can still have this meaning in some contexts?

Comment: That's what _not necessarily_ implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These choices don't affect each other.

- You could choose either *would* or *used to*, with significant changes in meaning as mentioned by Kate. *Used to* clearly communicates a past that is no longer true. This might be because the baby now eats differently, or we sometimes use this language when recalling a past so long ago that the actions in it are disconnected from present reality. "Oh look, here's a picture of you as a baby! You used to eat everything..." Or if the subject no longer exists: "My grandad used to eat peas until the day he died." *Would* can have various meanings, but it's also a past tense of *will*, so it could bring in a connotation of the baby's *willingness* to eat certain foods. Or it could simply describe habitual practices in the past: "When my grandad ate peas, he would always mush them up with his fork."
- Whichever phrase you choose for the first phrase, it has no effect on the choice of "everything" vs "anything" or "except" vs "except for."
- You could choose "everything but" or "anything but" with *very little* change in meaning, if any, in this context. There would be more impact in this context: "Hello, candy store owner. Please give me everything/anything but licorice." If I said "I like everything/anything but," I'm simply expressing preference; but "everything" means literally "every thing," and would be a much more expensive order than "any (one) thing."

Comment: so saying that "would do" and "used to" are synonymous is wrong. They both describe something that is no longer true but with differeences you mentioned. Would =habitual behaviour and willingness. Used to=no longer does. Right?