# "had once known" vs "used to know"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

"She was no longer Mary---the Mary he **had once known/used to know.**"

Do **both phrases** mean more or less the same? Or they have different meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, any distinction in meaning is miniscule. But note that [*used to* can be used in other ways](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/308861/used-to-would-do-except-for-anything-everything), some of which would have more difference. For instance, "I used to X back then" can mean "I would X from time to time back then." There would be a difference between "There was the yard he had mowed once" and "There was the yard he used to mow."